# Lessen noise from adjacent room

Tags: sound-proofing, noise-reduction, sound-deadening

I have a housemate who tends to snore during the night. Since our rooms share a wall, I tend to hear it. We live in an apartment building made from concrete panels.

I'd like to do some basic soundproofing so that it doesn't bother me (at least not as much), but 1) I'm not the owner of the apartment and I can't make huge changes, and 2) I want the room to still look good after changes are made.

I don't need to soundproof the whole room, it's just this wall that bothers me. I've been thinking of putting up fabric acoustic tiles, but I'd prefer not to cover the whole wall for both cost-saving and aesthetic reasons.

What portion of the wall do the acoustic tiles need to cover to effectively reduce noise from the other room? How much space should there be between each? Where and how should I place them?

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Blocking noise isn't something you do at a single point, so if you can't cover the whole wall you aren't likely to get good results.

Comment: Could you hang up a blanket? Or use a white noise machine?

Comment: Just wondering is there a common air register for heat in the room, my sister in law snores horribly and when she visits both my wife and I cannot sleep because it is so loud. I found installing a baffle in the register really helped the walls are expanded steel and concrete on both sides so the door and vents were the only way for the sound to get in. I used a heat resistant foam, it may have slightly reduced the air flow into the 2 rooms but that and some acoustic tiles on the spare bedroom door cut the noise to a tolerable level.

Comment: @EdBeal Interesting point. There isn't a common air register in my case, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be approached from a different angle. If snoring is the only reason you desire sound deading then talk your housemate into purchasing a snore suppressor. Earplugs would be far cheaper and easier than creating a wall sound barrier.

Comment: I've tried earplugs, but they're not comfortable to sleep with and they tend to fall out.

As for snore suppressors, I can mention it to him, but I doubt he's going to want to get something like that. His snoring doesn't bother him.